# MVC 4 SelectList Class, what is it doing exaclty?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to fully conceptualize what exactly the SelectList class is doing when I call it.

Consider the following code:

```
public SelectList GetSelectList(string selectedItem)
{
    return new SelectList(ItemList, "Key", "Value", "Group", selectedItem, null, null);
}
```

Now my greater wisdom tells me that each time I call my method `GetSelectList()` it instantiates a `SelectList class constructor`, that in-turn loops over my `ItemList`.

Is my wisdom correct here?  It may seem like a silly question, but I'm interested in the exact mechanics because on my page GET requests I do not want unnecessary looping occurring for lists that have none-yet `selectedItem`.  I'd rather just produce a cached version of a specific `SelectList`.

Comment: Yes, it loops over `ItemList`. Its a code short cut for creating `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` used by the `DropDownListFor()` method. It uses reflection to determine the properties to assign to the `Value`, Text`, Group` etc properties so in slightly slower than (say) `var selectList = ItemList.Select(i => new SelectListItem { Text = i.Key, Value = i.Value, ...});` but its insignificant

Comment: Note also that if your binding to a property in your model, setting the `Selected` property is pointless. The option that will be selected is based on the value of the property and `selectedItem` is ignored (the only time its respected is when you use `@Html.DropDownList("ThisIsNotAProperty", Model.yourSelectList)`

Comment: @StephenMuecke - Post this as an answer instead of a comment.  :-)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Yes, please post as answer and I'll accept as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `new SelectList(..)` will iterate over the items in the collection and generates `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`. You can view the [source code here](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/MultiSelectList.cs) (look for example at the `GetListItemsWithValueField()` method).

Using the `SelectList()` constructor is a short cut for using (say)

```
IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selectList = ItemList.Select(i => new SelectListItem()
{
  Value = i.Key, // may need to add `.ToString()`
  Text = i.Value,
  ...
});
```

but it uses reflection to get the properties defined by the `dataValueField`, `dataValueField` etc. parameters so its a millisecond or 2 slower (it really just comes down to personal preference and whether your happy using "magic strings")

Note also that setting the `selectedValue` parameter will be ignored if your binding to a model property. Its the value of the property which determines which option is selected, so in terms of caching the `SelectList`, you can just ignore it.

I would however recommend that you reconsider caching a `SelectList`. If the values of `ItemList` rarely change, then `ItemList` may be a good candidate for being cached, and any method which adds or modifies an item in the collection can call a method to invalidate the cache, but caching the `SelectList` may present some difficulties in ensuring its invalidated if the underlying collection changes. Creating a `SelectList` or `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` are both blindingly fast and insignificant in the performance of your app.

Comment: Its a countries and states list that I'd like to cache, they rarely change - wink.  Its painful for me to think that for every GET request my app must iterate a list of countries and states.  When we start getting hundreds of thousands and millions of hits, the cached results will be beneficial.  Cache what you can.

Comment: I agree if the countries and states rarely change you should consider caching their collections to minimize database calls, but I don't agree that you should cache the `SelectLists` you create from them. If you do, you will need to consider how you invalidate the cache when a change is made to the underlying collection without tying the data models to your view models

Comment: In my case I've created a static SLDataCache class that caches all data that doesn't change or need to change.  If a new country comes into existence, stopping and starting the app will re-load from DB into my SLDataCache.  I could put a timer and a lock on the cache, but since my data there is static in every sense, it doesn't make sense to do so.  Otherwise I use Redis or MSSQL caching.

Comment: So in this regard, it makes sense to cache my SelectLists to avoid all the unnecessary looping.